# jQuery: Do not open popup when new tab/window requested?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-experience

I'm trying to make user experience as fine as possible. I have two links: to login and to join. When user clicks them, the site darkens and popup (div, not new window of course) appears with appropriate forms.

In addition, those links have valid URLs. Those forms can be achieved by dedicated URL.

My question is, how can I prevent popup from opening when user wants it to open in new tab or window? Currently, it works great if someone chooses `Open in new tab` or `Open in new window` from context menu, but if someone just clicks with <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>, the popup opens. This is not expected, I'd like to allow users to use those shortcuts to have those in separate tab/window.

Is there any more fancy way to solve this than listening for <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect shift key and control key in the click event (not sure if that is whay you mean by "listening for .... pessed" because we can check in the click event and not keyboard event. Otherwise, I am sorry for you time)

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        .... // Don't show the div dialog
    } else if (e.shilfKey) {
        .... // Don't show the div dialog
    } else if (e.metaKey) {
        .... // Don't show the div dialog
    } else {
        .... // Show the dialog.
    }
});
```

Sincerely hope this helps.